# What is the doppler (frequency) shift called in the time domain

Tags: doppler-effect

Almost all descriptions of the 'Doppler shift' are with reference to the change in frequency of a regular sinusoid or pulse train.

What would be the appropriate term (for the same base physics effect) when considering the time domain period or inter-pulse delay changes for a returned signal reflected off a moving object?

The key aim of the question is fix the labelling into the time domain way of thinking to allow readers of explanations to drop their pre-conceived frequency domain views when considering randomly spaced return pulses (and the potential post processing that can be done on them).

Ideally the term would have a short name or individual attached to it, rather than some long phrase that 'gets lost in translation'.  It's not 'dither', but that goes in the right direction of being easily understood in the time domain.

Comment: It's called Doppler effect. Time/frequency domain are just different ways to analyze the same physical data.

Comment: @CuriousOne, do you have a reference or web page that actually describes the 'Doppler effect' purely from a time series perspective? (every page I've ever seen always says its a frequency shift effect ;-). A single example would be sufficient.

Comment: You could try signal processing and the digital audio effects community, physicists don't care much about the Doppler effect. Where these things matter in the time domain is special and general relativity.

Comment: "Pulse stretching" is appropriate for a receding radial velocity. The opposite of that would be pulse "compression" but that term is reserved for a particular type of radar signal processing.